# Multiple variable assignments in php

Tags: php

```
$a=$b=$c=0;
```

and

```
$a=0;
$b=0;
$c=0;
```

what's the difference between them?or they are same?Some one can give me some idea?

Comment: Yes, they are same

Comment: The main difference is readability of your code. The first line is an awful concatenation that is hard to read. The second one is much more readable.

Comment: Its just a shorthanded way of saying the same thing. Some people prefer to save lines others prefer it to be more immediately readable. Personal preference.

Comment: The first is easily done in 1 line, the second is 3 lines, but functionally they are identical.... but if you do use the 1-liner, I'd suggest a space around each `=` to help readability

Answer (score 0):

They are the same.

The first one is:

```
$a is equal to $b is equal to $c is equal to 0
```

and the second one is:

```
$a is equal to 0
$b is equal to 0
$c is equal to 0
```